# How to use a variable outside function onBindViewHolder declared inside it?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating a basic ToDo list app in kotlin and have stored it's data in SQLiteDatabase. I am trying to add a swipe to delete functionality. The functionality works but I am unable to pass the id of the task to the delete functionality. Can I use the list[p1].id from the DisplayAdapter in the onCreate class above it?

Displayadapter:

```
class DashboardAdapter(private val activity: dashboard, var list: MutableList<ToDo>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.ViewHolder>(){


        override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
            return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_layout,p0,false))

        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
            holder.toDoName.text = list[p1].name
            holder.toDoName.setOnClickListener{
                val id_long = list[p1].id
                val intent = Intent(activity,subtask_list::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(INTENT_TODO_ID,id_long)
                intent.putExtra(INTENT_TODO_NAME,list[p1].name)
                activity.startActivity(intent)
            }

        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return list.size
        }


        fun removeItem(todoId: Long) {
            val db = DBHandler(null).db
            db.delete(TABLE_TODO_ITEM,"$COL_TODO_ID=?", arrayOf(todoId.toString()))
            db.delete(TABLE_TODO,"$COL_ID=?", arrayOf(todoId.toString()))
        }

        class ViewHolder(v : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v){
            val toDoName : TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_todo_name)
        }

    }
```

removeItem is the delete funtion which requires a list.id

Calling the removeItem function:

```
val itemTouchHelperCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
                DashboardAdapter(dashboard(),dataset).removeItem(list[p1].id)
            }

        }
        val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallback)
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_dashboard)
```

I have tried declaring but cannot understand how to initialize the following:

```
private var dataset= mutableListOf<ToDo>()

    lateinit var list: MutableList<ToDo>
```

I also have a refreshList function outside the displayAdapter to refresh the ToDo list once updated:

```
private fun refreshList(){
        rv_dashboard.adapter  = DashboardAdapter(this,dbHandler.getToDo())
    }
```

How to either initialize the list variable or get the lists[p1].id from the displayadapter?

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to go about this. I recommend you do not perform your DB and navigation logic in your adapter, instead implement a listener for item click and write your DB logic in the Fragment/Activity (Would be better to have the logic in your ViewModel). I have refactored your code.

**Adapter:**

```kotlin
class DashboardAdapter(
    private var list: MutableList<ToDo>,
    private val itemClickListener: (Long) -> Unit,
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.create(parent, itemClickListener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.bind(list[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    fun refreshList(list: List<Todo>) {
        this.list = list
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeItemAt(position: Int) {
        list.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    class ViewHolder private constructor(
        v: View,
        private val itemClickListener: (Long) -> Unit,
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
        private val toDoName: TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_todo_name)

        fun bind(todo: ToDo) {
            toDoName.text = todo.name
            toDoName.setOnClickListener {
                itemClickListener.invoke(todo.id)
            }
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup, itemClickListener: (Long) -> Unit): ViewHolder {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rv_child_layout, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(view, itemClickListener)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment/Activity:**

```kotlin
private lateinit var listAdapter: DashboardAdapter

fun setupRecyclerView() {
    ...

    listAdapter = DashboardAdapter(list) { id: Long ->
        // Navigate to sub list task activity
    }

    rv_dashboard.adapter = listAdapter

    val swipeCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        ): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            val position = viewHolder.adapterPosition

            //Get id from list and delete from database

            listAdapter.removeItemAt(position)
        }
    }

    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeCallback)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv_dashboard)
}
```

To refresh your list call the `refreshList` function in the adapter:

```kotlin
listAdapter.refreshList(list)
```

Comment: what would i give parameter for the itemClickListener in  refreshList function outside the DisplayAdapter?

Comment: what refreshList function??

Comment: I have a function outside the DisplayAdapter to refresh the ToDo list: private fun refreshList(){
        rv_dashboard.adapter  = DashboardAdapter(dbHandler.getToDo())
    }

Comment: Post your refreshList in your question. Ill update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Have updated my answer. You do not need to recreate the adapter to refresh the list.

Comment: Just so you know. `removeItemAt` would reflect the removal of a item. Only use `refreshList` if actually need to refresh the whole list.

Comment: i am sorry to ask this but how do you navigate to dashboard activity? i think the rest is working great and i have not initialised the lateinit thats why the app is crashing

Comment: I wrote that comment wrong. In your implementation, you were setting a click listener in `onBindViewHolder` wherein you were navigating to `subtask_list` activity. Do that in the fragment now, where I have put the comment for navigation

Comment: I cant, Intent is giving me error saying that no intent function is there,i really need this to work

Comment: Lets move this dicussion to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223332/discussion-between-siddharth-sharma-and-tanishq-kashyap)

Comment: i cant, dont have enough reputation

Comment: i wrote this for navigation and still its giving error that its not initialised: val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra(INTENT_TODO_ID,id)

Comment: This should work. Have you imported the package `import android.content.Intent`

Comment: I don't know what you are doing wrong but that should be working as it is just a class and you can create its object anywhere in the project irrespective of what type the containing class is.

Comment: that i solved but now i assigned the adapter to rv_dashboard just under the listAdapter function: ```rv_dashboard.adapter = listAdapter``` and is giving error that it cannot be null

Comment: You need to initialize `listAdapter` before that. `listAdapter = DashboardAdapt... `

Comment: and its asking me value for parameter itemClickListener

Comment: Look at the answer. listAdapter = DashboardAdapter(list) { id: Long ->
        // Navigate to sub list task activity
    }

Comment: in the exact order as in answer? `listAdapter = DashboardAdapter(list) { id: Long ->
        // Navigate to sub list task activity
    }

    rv_dashboard.adapter = listAdapter`